# TensorFlow: "TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead"

Tags: tensorflow

When I run the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

pivot = tf.constant([1, 2])
my_ones = tf.ones([2, 3])
padded = tf.pad(my_ones, [[pivot[0], 0], [1,1]])
sess = tf.Session()

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init_op)
my_ones_var = sess.run(padded)
print("my_ones, ", my_ones_var)
```

...I get an error on the line containing `tf.pad()`:

```
TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** You can't currently define a tensor argument as a list (of lists) containing tensors, so you'll have to build the paddings manually.

This error occurs on the following line:

```
padded = tf.pad(my_ones, [[pivot[0], 0], [1,1]])
```

The reason it fails is because `pivot[0]` is a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor), [`tf.pad()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pad) expects a `tf.Tensor` for its second argument, and TensorFlow does not currently convert a list (of lists) containing `tf.Tensor` objects into a new tensor. The workaround is to use [`tf.pack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pack) to build the padding tensor manually:

```
paddings = tf.pack([tf.pack([pivot[0], 0]), [1, 1]])
padded = tf.pad(my_ones, paddings)
```

We're looking into ways that this could happen automatically, so your original could would work.

---

**EDIT:** Automatic packing is now supported (since TensorFlow 0.9), so the following code will now work:

```
padded = tf.pad(my_ones, [[pivot[0], 0], [1, 1]])
```

Comment: THANKS!!!!! At last I can continue working. I tried tf.pack but in diferent places with no luck. Yes, this things should be automatic. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

hi all the issue is due to Keras version. I tried above all without any success. Uninstall Keras and install via pip. It worked for me.

I was facing this error with Keras 1.0.2 & resolved with Keras 1.2.0

Hope this will help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You just have to update all the line with tf.concat

for example

means = tf.concat(0, [tf.reduce_mean(tf.gather(vectors,                  tf.reshape(tf.where(tf.equal(assignments, c) ), [1, -1])), reduction_indices=[1]) for c in range(k)])

should be changed to

means = tf.concat([tf.reduce_mean( tf.gather(vectors,tf.reshape(              tf.where( tf.equal(assignments, c)), [1, -1])), reduction_indices=[1]) for c in range(k)], 0)